# why toggle button not support in widget application in android

Tags: android, android-widget, togglebutton

possible duplicate,

hello all,

I am not getting the reason that why `ToggleButton` was not available for application widget (Home screen widget).

I have google it but not getting any reason. Does anybody knows the reason

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Widget layouts are based on `RemoteView`, which does not support every kind of layout or view widget:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: that's I know I am looking for the reason

Comment: App Widgets run within the home screen process, so as I understand it RemoteViews is a mechanism to have UI operations execute your own code within this process. You will see RemotableViewMethod annotations within the Android source code against the widgets that support it. As to the specifics of why only a small subset of views have these annotations, you might have to delve deeper in the code to find out. The code being executed is serialized so that it can be run in the seperate home screen process, so there will obviously be some limitations there.